# jQuery .next('div') toggle not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

I'm having a problem toggling the visibility of a sibling div using jQuery. What I want to do is show/hide this sibling div when the `.detailsbtn` link is clicked. If I move the `.projdetails div`immediately following the '.detailsbtn' the script works but I need to put it after a 2nd link.

The HTML is structured as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" id="hp" class="btn btn-info detailsbtn">Project Details</a>
<a href="javascript:void();" class="btn btn-success">Launch Website</a>
<div class="projdetails">This is the hp details</div>
```

The jQuery is as follows:

```
$('.projdetails').hide();

$('.detailsbtn').click(function () {
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.siblings()` instead of `.next()` as next only looks for immediately following sibling

```
$(this).siblings('div.projdetails').toggle();
```

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: @iztel it will be nice of you if you can accept the answer, if it is helping you.